# Checking if the object exists in the Update() function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my own class which:

- inherits from `MonoBehaviour` (this makes it behave as `GameObject`)
- contains `Instance2D` which stores the assigned `GameObject`
- The object is created with `new Wall()` (Maybe this way causes some problems?)

I need MonoBehaviour because I perform GameObject operations in this class.

Maybe it is necessary to get around it somehow?

Class:

```
public class Wall : MonoBehaviour {
  public Guid Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public GameObject Instance2D {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

I would like to check in the `Update()` function whether the object currently exists.

I tested the solutions:

- `if (myObject != null)`
- `if (myObject)`
- I can't search by name because the object is created dynamically with different names

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Similarly, I do not check if there is an object at all.

I looked through various entries about checking an object if it exists but I found nothing that works. If 50 frames are taken in a given second, it turns out that the object is present and not present and it causes an error.

Is there any specific and always correct solution?

Comment: `The object is created with new Wall()` yeah in general that's "not allowed" for `MonoBehaviour` .. you should actually get a warning about it ..

Comment: In general `if (myObject)` should do the best job ... otherwise please provide a more complete reproducible example of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

So since you have an Monobehaviour and you want, monobehaviour functions, you will probably need to add it to a gameObject.
But it depends on the Functions you are using

```
GameObject myObj= new GameObject("Name or leave empty");
myObj.AddComponent<Wall>();
```

This should do it, if not, please post a bit more info.